# I'm getting traceback error in matplotlib legend figure though i was working before and the same code is available in others site which is still work

Tags: matplotlib, legend

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

xaxis = np.array([2, 4, 6, 10, 11, 15])
yaxis = np.array([1, 4, 5, 8, 14, 10])

#                     figsize = (x, y)
figaround = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor = "m", edgecolor = "c", linewidth = "7")
jb = figaround.add_axes([1,1,1,1])
jb.plot(xaxis, yaxis, "p-k", ms=12, mec="m", mfc="g")

# title
plt.title("Linear Graph", fontsize = 25, color = "k")
plt.xlabel("X-Axis Data", fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel("Y-Axis Data", fontsize = 15)

# x, y axis limit
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.xlim(0, 20)

plt.legend(["Linear Graph"])

plt.show()
```

**above this 2nd last line, **
`plt.legend(["Linear Graph"])`

*TypeError: 'list' object is not callable*

this error i'm getting here, code recognize legend property as list and no string shows in the graph that i'm expecting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No5TN.png)

based on the same code, i'm expecting the thing which has been shown in the picture above.
`plt.legend(["Linear Graph"])`

Comment: The only mistake is you passed a `string` to linewidth (e.g. `linewidth = "7"`). It should be an `int`. Make sure your packages are up to date. Otherwise the code worked as expected. I'm voting to close the question as caused by a typo / not reproducible. [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54VDU.png). **Tested in `python 3.11`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`**

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your exact error using Python 3.8.10 and matplotlib version 3.6.2.

However if you use `plt.figure()` you should pass linewidth as a `int` parameter, not `str`:

```
figaround = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), facecolor="m", edgecolor="c", linewidth=7)
```

In addition, please check if passing `[1,1,1,1]` to `add_axes` is really intended as your Axes object starts at right-upper corner of your Figure and [spans outside of it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matplotlib-figure-figure-add_axes-in-python/).

Also if you still get an error you can try adding legend as label to your plot like this:

```
jb.plot(xaxis, yaxis, "p-k", ms=12, mec="m", mfc="g", label="Linear Graph")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```